# short_open_tag setting ignored by PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, php-ini

My PHPUnit tests keep failing when trying to tests any .php files in my (legacy code) application that begin with the short open tag (`<?` instead of `<?php`).

But in my `php.ini` file, the `short_open_tag` is set to `On`.

The application runs fine. Why is PHPUnit getting upset over the short open tag? I've looked for other `php.ini` files, and could only find the one at `/etc/php.ini`. My `.htaccess` file doesn't affect this setting either. What else could be causing this?

Comment: Just use `<?php` instead of `<?`...

Comment: I'm working with legacy code where there are probably hundreds to thousands of instances of the short open tags and it's not feasible to make that kind of code change before we have unit tests...

Comment: Can you add the error message you get?

Comment: to be sure if `short_open_tag` is enabled, type `php -i |grep 'short_open_tag'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it to work and the solution is frustrating: My application is on a VM and the `php.ini` file within the VM had the correct setting. However, PHPUnit was using the `php.ini` file on my local machine, which had `short_open_tag` set to `Off`. Changing that setting fixed my problem.

(I'm still unsure of why PHPUnit uses the other `php.ini`, but I think that's outside the scope of this question.)

Answer (score 4):

**General solution**

1) Check which php.ini file is loaded (command line:  `php --ini`)

2a) Set in that php ini file: `short_open_tag = on`

2b) Set in .htaccess file: `php_value short_open_tag 1`

3) Restart the server (command line: `service httpd restart`)

Comment: I use a phpunit.xml config file to run tests, and adding `<ini name="short_open_tag" value="1" />` inside the `<php>` tag doesn't turn that setting on. Are you aware of how to turn this setting on using the phpunit.xml config file?

Comment: So I posted the above question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277342/changing-php-ini-configuration-option-in-phpunit-xml, and turns out you can't change the `short_open_tag` setting at runtime. So, I don't think passing the option will work. (Good general solution though)

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit uses PHP-cli module of PHP. And PHP-cli has another `.ini` file for its configuration. I am using ubuntu 14.04, in my case

> `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`    //used for web compiler
>
> **`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`**      // Used for PHP-cli, **you need to set `short_open_tag=On` here**